# Mongo sort by date unless a condition is met?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Supposed I have the following data:

| Time | Submitted |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | True |
| 2 | True |
| 3 | True |
| 4 | False |
| 5 | False |
| 6 | False |

My goal is to get either the the oldest unsubmitted OR the newest submitted. This is for loading user timesheets, so if they have an old unsubmitted timesheet, I want to load that by default. If not I want to show them their most current timesheet.

After the query I'd expect the data back in this order:

| Time | Submitted |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | False |
| 5 | False |
| 6 | False |
| 3 | True |
| 2 | True |
| 1 | True |

Notice the first 3 records are false so they sort by ascending time while the last 3 records are true so they sort by descending time.

Here is a mongoplayground sample of the data:

https://mongoplayground.net/p/yEtgMOfZ_ik

I'm guessing this can be done by projecting some value to use as the sort by, but I can't wrap my head around what that needs to be.

Comment: It would be better if you can provide the data in json documents instead of tabular format. It will be easier to work with it in https://mongoplayground.net/

Comment: Good suggestion, added it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a sort on `submitted` already: `false` sorts before `true` (0 vs 1 in many languages).  So that's the first key to sort on.

When `submitted=false`, you want a ascending order for time (4, 5, 6) and when it's `true`, you want the *opposite*.

You can create an additional key to sort on Time based on whether or not it was submitted and use *negative-numbers* to change the sort order when it's submitted true/false.

Here, I'm creating `timeSort` which will negate the time when `submitted=true`. So 3 becomes -3 and in ascending order, -3 < -2 < -1. Whereas 4, 5, 6 remain as is so 4 < 5 < 6 in ascending order.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      timeSort: {
        $multiply: [
          "$time",
          { $cond: [ "$submitted", -1, 1 ] }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      submitted: 1,
      timeSort: 1
    }
  },
  { $unset: "timeSort" }
])
```

You can flip the 1 and -1 around in `$cond` and in `timeSort` in `$sort`, gives the same results.

```js
[
  { "time": 4, "submitted": false },
  { "time": 5, "submitted": false },
  { "time": 6, "submitted": false },
  { "time": 3, "submitted": true },
  { "time": 2, "submitted": true },
  { "time": 1, "submitted": true }
]
```

[Mongo Plaground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ffgYfw7iyky)

Comment: Awesome! I couldn't wrap my head around what to set/project as an additional property to sort on

Answer (score 4):

I think aneroid answer fits perfectly into your requeriment and I've upvoted it thinking should be the accepted answer.

But when I read the question I though this is the clearly example to use [$facet](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/). So I will post the use of `facet` in case helps someone.

Using `$facet` you can create "two ways" or "two queries" and compute them separately... which is what you want, compute `true values` and `false values` independently.

So you can try this query:

The trick here is create the two sorts independently each one. First `true_value` will be an array where only exists `submitted` values as `true` and it will be sort by `time: -1`.

On the other hand is `false_values` which will filter by `false` and sort by `1`.

So concating arrays and modifying output to get the same format you can get the result.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$facet": {
      "true_value": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "submitted": true
          }
        },
        {
          "$sort": {
            "time": -1
          }
        }
      ],
      "false_value": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "submitted": false
          }
        },
        {
          "$sort": {
            "time": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "result": {
        "$concatArrays": [
          "$false_value",
          "$true_value"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$result"
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$result"
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IERo6_uCPDe)

Comment: This is actually super helpful! I was just trying to get $facet to work myself and almost wrote the exact same code, but couldnt get it to work. If I swap $setUnion in my code for $concatArrays that you used it, it works. For some reason $unionWith and then $unwinding caused my sorting to be undone.

Comment: Very nice explanation of how to use `$facet`. Still getting my head around _when_ to use it.

Comment: Curious if you know: I was originally trying to figure out a way to use $group for this as I found a couple threads based on that, but read that it doesn't guarantee order.  Since its a similar concept (put things in two lists and sort it) do you know if $facet in this case would guarantee the order? I have no idea how to find out that kind of info, like my problem with $setUnion/$unwind producing a wrong result but $concatArray/$unwind being correct.

Comment: @JoeJankowiak From [the docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/), _[`$setUnion`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/#mongodb-expression-exp.-setUnion) ignores the order of the elements._ But `$concatArray` will concatenate the arrays in the order of the arrays as specified and using the elements from each array in the order they exist.

Answer (score 2):

While appreciating the other answers' simplicity and efficiency, I want to propose another alternative that can leverage indices.

With below index:

```js
{
    "submitted": 1,
    "time": -1
}
```

We can first query the `false` data, then `$unionWith` with the `true` data.

```js
db.submissions.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      submitted: false
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      time: 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$unionWith": {
      "coll": "submissions",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            submitted: true
          }
        },
        {
          "$sort": {
            time: -1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

From this [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eet41jniFpE), you can see that it is able to do `IXSCAN` instead of `COLLSCAN`.

Comment: TIL about [`$unionWith`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unionWith/#definition). But does this approach rely on an edge-case of the results being the in right order? The docs say _"The order in which the combined result set documents are output is unspecified."_

Comment: @aneroid That is a valid concern. Even for the SQL counterpart `UNION ALL`, I think [there is no guarantee in the order](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/316818/are-results-from-union-all-clauses-always-appended-in-order). But from my practical experience, the behaviour is usually a simple append to the end of the previous query result. I would describe this approach as working well for most cases, but for perfect, no-surprise behaviour, OP should opt for your accepted answer.